# iptables drop negative DNS responses

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, iptables, iproute2

How to drop incoming negative DNS responses in Linux? (I want a timeout instead)
I'm thinking of creating an iptables rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m u32 ...
```

From wireshark:

```
000E start of IP Packet (fixed, at first, I wrote 0010)
0022 start of UDP Packet
002A start of DNS message
002C  Flags
        .... .... .... 0000 = Reply code: No error (0)
        .... .... .... 0011 = Reply code: No such name (3)
```

I think the offset for -m u32 is counted from the ip header. Also subtracting 2 to get a 32bit.

```
$ echo $(( 0x002C - 0x000E - 2 ))
28
```

The mask for the last 4 bits is 0xF
So the rule should be something like this:

```
iptables -I INPUT -p udp --sport 53 -m u32 --u32 "28&0xF=3" -j DROP
```

Comment: out of curiosity - why?

Comment: The negative answer comes first and dnsmasq returns it. Then comes the positive answer from a slow server

Comment: @user447503 You're getting two answers, with different data, to a single query?  Why?

Comment: @Shane One is my ISP DNS, the other is the VPN DNS. I want to have both.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dropping negative responses worked fine until I added more than one `search` domain to `/etc/resolv.conf`: libc tries the suffixes sequentially and if I drop the negative responses for the wrong suffix initially picked by the libc resolver it gives up with a timeout before it tries the right suffix.

So I decided to *delay* the negative responses instead of dropping them. This makes sure `dnsmasq` gets the positive response from the right server before it gets the negative responses from the other servers.

Delaying is done not with `iptables`, but with `iproute2`. Here's my configuration for a modern systemd Linux:

/etc/modules-load.d/my-tc.conf

```
ifb
```

/etc/systemd/system/my-tc.service

```
[Unit]
Before=NetworkManager.service

[Service]
Type=oneshot
ExecStart=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/ip link set dev ifb0 up && /usr/bin/tc qdisc add dev ifb0 root netem delay 900ms"
ExecStop=/bin/bash -c "/usr/bin/tc qdisc del dev ifb0 root && /usr/bin/ip link set dev ifb0 down"
RemainAfterExit=true

[Install]
WantedBy=network.target
```

/etc/NetworkManager/dispatcher.d/my-tc.sh

```
#!/bin/bash
if [ "enp0s3 up" = "$1 $2" ]; then
  tc qdisc add dev enp0s3 ingress
  tc filter add dev enp0s3 parent ffff: protocol ip \
    u32 \
      match ip protocol 17 0xff \
      match ip sport 53 0xffff \
      match u32 0x03 0x0F at 28 \
    flowid 1:1 action mirred egress redirect dev ifb0
fi
```

Answer (score 5):

Offset for DNS flags in ip packet is 28bytes and you need to check last 2 bits in 2byte field
u32 rule for that is `"28&0x000F=0x03"`

My test rule is: `iptables -A INPUT -m u32 -p udp --sport 53 --u32 "28&0x000F=0x03" -j LOG`

BTW I like the idea to use this firewall rule for split horizon DNS, going to test it for some of my networks.

Comment: I understood, except for the offset. Why it's not 26? I thought that --u32 checks a 4-byte field and you need to subtract 2

Comment: real offset is 30 bytes, but it's a bit longer rule: "0x1e&0x30000=0x30000"

Comment: (Edited). The offset that works is still 28: "28&0x0000000F=3". Thanks anyway

Comment: You're right, 0x0F mask is more correct.

Comment: I had to port the filter to `iproute2`, see my answer.

Answer (score 2):

This drops BIND9 "rejected" replies to the current spoofed UDP queries!

```
iptables -F OUTPUT 
#iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j LOG --log-prefix="OUT-UPD-RAW : "
#iptables -A OUTPUT -m u32 -p udp --sport 53 --u32 "28&0xFFFF=0x8105" -j LOG --log-prefix="STOPPED-DNS-REJECTED-REPLY "
iptables -A OUTPUT -m u32 -p udp --sport 53 --u32 "28&0xFFFF=0x8105" -j DROP
iptables -A OUTPUT -p udp --sport 53 -j LOG --log-prefix="OUT-UPD-SENT: "
```

Answer (score 2):

@DukeLion is correct, but you should also be aware of NOERROR but NOANSWER. To drop this too, add this iptables rule:

```
iptables -I INPUT -m u32 -p udp --sport 53 --u32 "32&0xFFFF=0x0000" -j DROP
```

PS. DNS RCODE in IP packet "real" offset is 31.5 bytes, so I don't like matching it use `0x1e&0x30000=0x30000`

Comment: To make it more robust, you can use it with `0x1b&0x80=0x80` to indicate this is a response, but since --sport 53 already implied this, so this is actually not needed.